# Is using a static class to facilitate access to appsettings acceptable?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some keys in the app.config file of my application that house email settings. The application I am currently developing for work has several places where I need to send off an email (mostly in error checking to let us know something bad happened). To make it easier to grab that setting where I need it (instead of going back to the app.config to look up the text string to use in `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"].ToString()` I created a simple static class to house a few readonly properties that return the values I need. Here's the basic structure

```
internal static Class myClass
{
    internal static string setting1
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"].ToString(); }
    }
    internal static string setting2
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherKey"].ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Is the way I am doing this acceptable? I can't find an issue with this but can't help thinking I'm missing something.

Additional Info:

I am aware of the method of simply using the Settings.Settings file.
I can't use the Settings.Settings file due to the code policy in place where I work, which would make the way I'm doing this unnecessary.

Edit: 
By "acceptable" I mean is it commonly done or considered a good idea? I realize the community at large cannot speculate on acceptability at my job.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "acceptable".  To me, wrapping `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` with an injectable interface so that I can mock the config dependency if need be is the "acceptable" route.  For you that might be overkill.  It all depends on your needs.  Personally however, I avoid static classes as much as possible to promote unit testability.

Comment: I think it's fine. If you do this often, create a helper method, something like `GetSettingsValue<T>(string settingName)` -- something that ensures that the value is convertible to `T` when accessing the key.

Comment: Acceptable to whom? It seems that the most significant restriction you may run into is whatever entity is prohibiting you from using the settings implementation provided in the VS designer. That's a pretty arbitrary restriction, and whatever motivates it might also lead to a prohibition against a static class or a similar singleton class like the `Settings` class you'd otherwise use. I don't see how anyone here at Stack Overflow can provide useful insight as to the restrictions you might run into.

Comment: If you don't do unit testing, or have no need to mock out the dependency on the static method calls, then it seems acceptable.

Comment: @DavidL I think I'll go with an Interface instead. I don't know why that didn't occur to me to start with. Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice to get some explanation with the downvotes. I thought it was a legitimate question? Perhaps I have worded it poorly? I will review and try to rework it to be more objective.

Comment: I think it's more the speculative nature than the question itself. It might be better in codereview.stackexchange.com. It's a very, very good question. As soon as you realized that you don't want your class talking to AppSettings directly you were onto something big. When you get the answer to that you'll find that it applies much more broadly. For me personally, dependency injection (I use Windsor) changed *everything*. Not because DI alone is so great but because it became a catalyst that changed the way I wrote code. It facilitates other best practices like unit testing.

Comment: What type of application is this (MVC, Web API, WCF, or something else?)  I've written one [blog post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/13/wcf-dependency-injection-in-5-minutes.html) about getting started with dependency injection in WCF, but I'd like to supplement that with posts to help with other types of apps. DI is a slightly confusing subject at first, but then you see it working and it just clicks. Sometimes it's easier to understand if you see it first instead of learning about it and then trying to do it.

Comment: @ScottHannen This application is a c# Console Application using .NET 4.5.2

Comment: I'll see if I can do another blog post later. In practice I might not use DI if it's something small, unless perhaps the classes are separate from the console app (which is a good idea because maybe you'll want to use them in a service or something else.) Some people will say don't use DI unless you need to (and they're mostly right.) But at the same time it's such a helpful tool that if you want to learn it, it doesn't hurt to use it as much as possible just to practice it.

Comment: static access doesn't mean you cannot test the code with other parameters, I don't know why some people keep repeating that argument. Dependency (DEPENDENCY!) injection in the case of global config parameters is simply an overkill and an over-design. You should chose the right tool for the right job. That's it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not bad but it can be better with a small tweak. (Ok, maybe not real small.)

If your classes depend on a static class and that class depends on `AppSettings` then your classes are still coupled to `AppSettings`. In other words, there's no other way for them to get their settings. That's a challenge if you want to unit test your class. That means that your unit test project has to have the same `<appSettings>` section. But what if you want two tests that use two different values for a setting? It's impossible. Or what if you have a class that needs settings and in a few years you want to use it in an ASP.NET Core application and there is no web.config? Then it won't work at all.

To avoid that you can do this:

```
public interface IMySettings
{
    string Setting1 {get;}
    string Setting2 {get;}
}

public class MyConfigurationSettings : IMySettings
{
    public string Setting1
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"].ToString(); }
    }
    public string Setting2
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherKey"].ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Then, in the class that needs the setting:

```
public class ClassThatNeedsSettings
{
    private readonly IMySettings _settings;

    public ClassThatNeedsSettings(IMySettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Then, when ever you create an instance of `ClassThatNeedsSettings` you pass an instance of a class that implements `IMySettings`, and the class will use that to retrieve settings. When your application is running you pass in `MyConfigurationSettings` so that your values come from `AppSettings`. But `ClassThatNeedsSettings` never knows that. It only knows that it's using an instance of `IMySettings`.

This is called "dependency injection." `ClassThatNeedsSettings` depends on `IMySettings` so you're "injecting" it into the constructor. That way `ClassThatNeedsSettings` receives what it needs. It's not responsible for creating it.

If you want to unit test, you can "mock" `IMySettings`. That is, you can create other classes that implement the interface and use them to pass in whatever values you want to test with. There are even tools like Moq that help you create those classes.

Typically if you use dependency injection you're also going to use a framework like Windsor, Unity, Autofac, or others to manage creating objects for you. It feels a little bit like bait-and-switch introducing that at the very end because it requires more learning and perhaps changing the way an application is configured. But this is why we use it, to prevent one class from having an absolute dependency on another which makes it less flexible and harder to test.

Comment: Just recoded to use the interface method instead and it is much cleaner looking, and will let me unit test, which I was afraid I would have to forego due to the static classes. I'm still really new to DI and mocking but your example gives me something great to go by as a starting point.

Comment: @Rocky, since you're new to DI, I suggest holding off on using IoC containers (e.g., Windsor and Autofac) for now.  You don't need them to write good code.  When used properly, they look like magic to a newbie.  When used improperly, they become the Service Locator pattern. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179002/ioc-containers-and-service-locator-pattern I remember being confused by IoC containers at first.

Comment: Agreed - it's easy to mix up the pattern and the tools that help us implement the pattern. I've used Windsor with console apps, mostly when I was figuring out how it works. I'm going to write some stuff on it later. Even though it's an odd fit for a console app, it does provide a way to demonstrate the tools without all the background noise about how to configure an app to use the container.

Comment: Good explanation, but it seems that `public MySettings(IMySettings settings)` should be changed to `public ClassThatNeedsSettings(...)` if you mean it is the constructor

Comment: @S.Serpooshan thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of testable code that addresses the commenters' concerns:

```
interface IEmailSettings {
    string Server { get; }
    string Sender { get; }
    string[] Recipients { get; }
}
```

If you store your settings in the app.config, use this:

```
class AppConfigEmailSettings : IEmailSettings {
    public AppConfigEmailSettings() {
        this.Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
        this.Sender = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sender"];
        this.Recipients = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recipients"].Split(';');
    }

    public string Server { get; private set; }
    public string Sender { get; private set; }
    public string[] Recipients { get; private set; }
}
```

If you store your settings in the database, use this:

```
class DatabaseEmailSettings : IEmailSettings {
    public DatabaseEmailSettings(string connectionString) {
        //code to connect to database and retrieve settings
    }
    //you can use the same fields and properties from AppConfigEmailSettings
}
```

For testing, you can use something like this:

```
class MockSettings : IEmailSettings {
    public string Server { get { return "localhost"; } }
    public string Sender { get { return "sender@example.com" } }
    public string[] Recipients { get { return new string[] { "r1@example.com" }; } }
}
```

You get the idea.  This code is easier to test than yours.  Also, if you inject `IEmailSettings` into the code that sends emails, you can easily change how you store your email settings by changing one line of code in your whole application.  That's the line that instantiates the `IEmailSettings` object to `AppConfigEmailSettings` or `DatabaseEmailSettings` or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody here can really define what is "acceptable" or not for your situation. I think what you're really asking is whether it is a good idea or where it might be a problem.

The short answer is that it *might* be acceptable for a simple solution, but for anything complex it's a bad idea. Static classes make unit testing very difficult (or impossible). Instead, as mentioned in your comments, the better option is to define an interface that has GetSettings methods on it. You can implement it with a class (not static) which just wraps calls to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings as David L mentioned in comments.

Any class which requires access to settings should have this interface passed into the constructor. You can either use an IoC container or create a new instance of your class to pass in (depending again on complexity) but more importantly you can now write unit tests and pass in a class with custom settings for your unit tests.