# How can I use the appsettings.json in static class in net 6 class library

Tags: c#, blazor, class-library, .net-6.0

I want to use the appsettings.json value in static class which in class library
now I know how to bind json value to class in program.cs like this

program.cs

```
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.Configure<APConfig>(configuration.GetSection(APConfig.Position));
```

APConfig.cs

```
public class APConfig
{
    public const string Position = "APConfig";

    public string RootPath { get; set; }
    public string API_URL { get; set; }
    public string TOKEN { get; set; }
    public string pwdkey { get; set; }
    public string pwdkey1 { get; set; }
    public string pwdkey2 { get; set; }

    public string GetProperty(string keyStr)
    {
        string value = Utility.DecryptTagContent((string)this.GetType().GetProperty(keyStr).GetValue(this));

        return value;
    }
}
```

How can I use the binded APConfig in a static class?

I found a solution:

```
public static class HttpContext
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext Current => _accessor.HttpContext;

    internal static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
}

public static class StaticHttpContextExtensions
{
    public static void AddHttpContextAccessor(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseStaticHttpContext(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        HttpContext.Configure(httpContextAccessor);
        return app;
    }
}
```

then use

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SetString(key, value);
HttpContext.Current.Session.GetString(key);
```

Comment: Your class should not be static.

Comment: so I should all use DI instead?

Comment: Yes, and then inject IConfiguration into your class.

Comment: You *can* use a static method, if you retrieve an `APConfig` instance from DI and pass it to the method. `Services.Configure<APConfig>` registers `APConfig` as a service with DI and specifies its properties should be filled from settings in `IConfiguration`, no matter where they come from - not just `appsettings.json`. This is used to make it easier to generate services that depend on setting objects

Answer (score 0):

I also like to have static access to the configuration values.

This StackOverflow question has several answers that may be helpful: [ASP.NET Core—access Configuration from static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885615/asp-net-core-access-configuration-from-static-class?fbclid=IwAR1YwXf5hWATWrqnWkkOSpsOR2Qvi0MIyCbseZCES1XleYa-D9ii3H_9MBE)

The key is that you need code that runs at startup that assigns the `IConfiguration` object or it's values to a static variable.

Then you can iterate over the values and place them in a static list. Something like public static `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Config= _config.AsEnumerable().ToList();` Or you could place those values in a public static `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score -1):

Accessing configuration requires an instance of `IConfiguration` which can be obtained using dependency injection.

Your class should then be non-static and have a DI constructor.